# Playwright codegen: Getting site can't be reached when logging in to site using Auth0

Tags: auth0, playwright

Trying to create a test to login to our existing site using the following test

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://xxxxxxxx.org/');
  await page.goto('https://XXXXXXX.auth0.com/login?state=xxxxxxxxxxx');
  await page.locator('#email').click();
  await page.locator('#email').fill(USERName);
  await page.getByLabel('Password').click();
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill(PASSWORD);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Log In' }).click();
  await page.goto('https://XXXXXXXX.auth0.com/login?state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  await page.goto('chrome-error://chromewebdata/');
});
```

Auth0 uses a callback but cannot seem to make it work with Playwright codegen, how can I capture the call back and use that to goto next page?

Comment: There's no way to help without a [mcve]. Thanks.